# Can't link library to module

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

It's taking me longer than I want to fix this issue. In a project I got a library that is used by a module, when the library is not added through the project structure panel, I got the variable in red, AKA, an error. As soon as I add the dependency the error is gone, everything is ok.

However, when I run the code I get errors saying that the type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MyClass.

I also have warnings saying that the definition could not be found.

But I know the errors were gone the moment I added the dependencies to my module.

I come from Flash Builder, so I don't really understand how IDEA works, but so far what I've been reading should be enough to get started.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to clarify some of your wording here. "library" and "module" should pretty much mean the same thing in flash. In fact libraries are pretty much just zipped up .as files. I think with your wording, you're making the question confusing.

Comment: I was talking about well defined concepts in IntellijIDEA. A library in the project structure is one thing, and a module is another. In case both can be used interchangeably, I'm referring to a Project Library and a Module.

Comment: okay so this is an IDE specific question then, not really anything to do with actionscript 3. Might wanna pull the tag from there because this has absolutely nothing to do with code.

Comment: Can you define "when I run the code" (how? via IDE or externally?), specify the errors, and confirm that you rebuilt the project, perhaps even cleared caches and restarted intellij.

Comment: When I compile the module, compile time errors appear that previously were cleared when I linked the dependencies. I've tried recompiling the project/module several times, there is no way to not have the errors.